# Direct initialization of object's variable using input from user

Tags: c++, class, object, initialization

For th following code:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test
{
public:
    int i;
    void get();
};
void Test::get()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the value of i: ";
    std::cin >> i; // Line 1
}
Test t;
int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.get();
    std::cout << "value of i in local t: "<<t.i<<'\n';
    ::t.get(); 
    std::cout << "value of i in global t: "<<::t.i<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Though I know what is happening in the above code i.e. the values are assigned to the local and global **t** , I am confused by the **line 1** as I am unable to understand how the value received from the user by the **line 1** is getting assigned to the **t.i** or **::t.i** .

It would be much appreciated If someone can help me explain **behind the scene of above problem **.

Comment: What is the confusion?  `get` stores the data in `i`.  So if you call `t.get` it stores it in `t::i`.  If you call `::t.get` it stores it in `::t::i`.

Comment: On line 1, the variable i is being assigned the value read from user. This is the instance variable of the object. Even if it is a global object or local object, the variable inside the instance method without explicit definition refers to the instance variable if there is no local declaration.

Comment: @RaviChandra: Please don't answer in the comments section. Thanks.

Comment: "Unable to understand" isn't really a question. What _specifically_ is the problem and what didn't you understand when you researched the topic?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `this` pointer and where it is implied?

Comment: Try changing the name of one instance of Test.  Next change the other instance name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Test::get()` is a *member function*.

Inside a member function, you can name any member variable of that class, and it'll affect the object you called the function on.

Read the chapter in your C++ book about classes.